# Cannot able to Download Files from WebView which have restriction of One time Download

Tags: android, webview, download-manager

I am facing a issue with downloading files with WebView that can only be downloaded one time by one user, after that url will not return the file. I am using Download Manager to handle the download of files.
So, In that case.

WebView makes a request to download file that it triggers setDownloadListener. In that function, we call another API with DownloadManager. That's why I am not able to download the file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity activity = this;
        WebView webView = activity.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(false);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                handleDownload(url,userAgent,contentDisposition,mimetype);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.40:8080");
    }

    public void handleDownload(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype){
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimetype);
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookies);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        String fileName = (new Date().getTime()) + URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this.getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
        final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does the server not serve the file a second time?

Comment: `That's why I am not able to download the file.` Dont understand a word.

Comment: Sorry, If I am unable to clarify. There is site where we have submit a form and in response we get the file. So, after submiting the form data and WebView trigger `setDownloadListener` we cannot use DownloadManager to download the file Because server will not response with file due to multiple request for same file.

Comment: Do not worry. Its not possible for now. here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184071997